# how to display an image on runtime on ImageView

Tags: android

I just want to ask that how can I display subsequent images on imageview. I am able to draw only one image at a time. what I want that after Displaying the first images it should go for taking the second image(second image will come on runtime) and display after some DELAY. And then third frame then 4th and so on..Using the setImageBitmap function I can display only one image and when i tried it for subsequent images I am not able to see the output.
I have also tried by using onDraw function but get same result.
Since I am getting image information in JNI interface. So can I use GLSurfaceview to display image. since I am new on Android. I never used OpenGL so can anybody please provide me some code for displaying subsequent images whether using GLsurfaceView or onDraw method of class view.
the code of what I am using is as follows...

```
class Display1 extends ImageView
{
Bitmap bMapScaled;
Bitmap bit;
Canvas c=new Canvas();
private static Context mContext = null;
private static final String TAG = "Example:Display";
public Display1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext=context;
}



    public void drawImage(byte[] data, int width, int height)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "drawImage2 called");
        bit=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
         bMapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bit, 150, 150, true);
        c.drawBitmap(bMapScaled, 0, 0, null);
        this.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled);
    }
// public native void drawImage(byte[] data, int width, int height);
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("itv");
    }
```

}

Please help me to solve this problem

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use *handlers* to implement the delay in-between a series of events:

```
    int page_resid = R.drawable.yourFirstImage; // put your first img here
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (page_resid <= R.drawable.tut8) {
                        image.setImageResource(page_resid);
                        page_resid++
                    } else {
                        finish(); // finished this series of img
                    }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }, k_DELAY_TIME_IN_MS); // put your delay time here
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But that is not what i want. I can not store the image in drawable. When i run the application I am getting the image from JNI interface. I just want to display that image and go back to the JNI to take second image and displayed on that image view.For the time delayed I have done the coding I just want to display images one by one while image are coming on run time.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this animation drawable...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

This might help you...

Comment: no I can not store the image in drawable.. I am getting images on run time after processing some function. Tell me the other way...

Comment: you should be able to use the standard procedure, setting the new Image to using setImageBitMap, can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: I have pasted the code.. this drawImage functions is regulary getting image to display from JNI inteface. But I am not able to see the output.. Now please help me...